# C++ snake dont move

Tags: c++

I have one problem. My snake is not moving. I cant find mistake. It draws map and snake head bt it doesnt move.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
bool gameOver;
const int width = 20;
const int height = 20;
int x, y, fruitX, fruitY;
enum eDirecton { STOP = 0, LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN };
eDirecton dir;

void Setup() {
    gameOver = false;
    dir = STOP;
    x = width / 2;
    y = height / 2;
    fruitX = rand() % width;
    fruitY = rand() % height;
}

void Draw() {
    system("cls");
    for(int i = 0; i < width + 2; i++) cout << "#";
    cout << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            if(j == 0) cout << "#";
            if(i == y && j == x)
                cout << "O";
            else if(i == fruitY && j == fruitX)
                cout << "F";
            else
                cout << " ";

            if(j == width - 1) cout << "#";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < width + 2; i++) cout << "#";
    cout << endl;
}

void Input() {
    if(_kbhit()) {
        switch(_getch()) {
        case 'a':
            dir = LEFT;
            break;
        case 'd':
            dir = RIGHT;
            break;
        case 'w':
            dir = UP;
            break;
        case 's':
            dir = DOWN;
            break;
        case 'q':
            gameOver = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}

void Logic() {
    switch(dir) {
    case LEFT:
        x--;
        break;
    case RIGHT:
        x++;
        break;
    case UP:
        y++;
        break;
    case DOWN:
        y--;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

int main() {
    Setup();
    while(!gameOver) {
        Draw();
        Input();
        Logic();
        // sleep (10)
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is what a debugger is for. Your debugger allows you to run your program one line at a time, examine the values of all variables, and observe your program's logical execution. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer. You are really asking how to debug a C++ program, and the answer to that is: use a debugger.

Comment: I guess its drawing the same snake for every call. So you can't see it moving.

Comment: @SudiptoRoy what shoud i do ?

Answer (score 0):

Start game right-away as you don't have a control key to start the game. Also it seems the UP/DOWN keys logic needs to interchange, as it is behaving opposite.

```
void Setup() {
   dir = DOWN;
   /* … */
}
```

// Control speed of animation . You may require `#include<chrono>`

```
int main() {
    Setup();
    while (!gameOver) {
        Draw();
        Input();
        Logic();
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(300));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's moving here (after pressing a key). Are you sure you're using the a,d,w,s keys and not the arrow keys?

You also need to switch the up an down logic, and provide a way to prevent going past the borders:

```
void Logic() {
    switch(dir) {
    case LEFT:
        x--;
        if (x < 0)
            x = width-1;
        break;
    case RIGHT:
        x++;
        if (x == width)
            x = 0;
        break;
    case UP:
        y--;
        if (y < 0)
            y = height-1;
        break;
    case DOWN:
        y++;
        if (y == height)
            y = 0;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Or the short style version like:

```
case LEFT:
    if (--x < 0)
        x = width-1;
    break;
```

To start te game immediately just set the direction in your `setup()`.

Comment: I am not dump... i using w,a,s,d keys. :/ nothing happend

Comment: A tried add this thing to start game imediatly but still doesnt work.

Comment: What program do you use ?

Comment: @JánMolitoris I'm not insinuating you're dumb.., it's that I used the arrow keys myself out of habit while testing your program, so I might as well ask in order to eliminate that possibility. I compiled the code in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

It's Moving
Make Sure You're using a,s,d,w Keys and not Arrow Keys .